# How to check the type of the variable in C at runtime?

Tags: c, type-conversion

Is it possible to check what type the variable is at any given point throughout the code?

For instance, say, i declare `char y = 1`; and function `int SomeFunction (int)`. I then will pass `y` to `someFunction`, it will get converted to an `int` and ultimately `int` will be returned.

I know this because of function declaration. I would like, however to confirm that inside `someFunction`, variable is in fact of type `int` and variable returned from `someFunction` is as well an `int`.

Can this be done in C, or function declaration should be relied upon instead? **Does C programming language provide any mechanism to check variable type at runtime?**

Comment: The variable inside of `someFunction` is _in fact_ an `int` because you say so.

Comment: So, C programming language provides no mechanism to check variable type at runtime?

Comment: In C, types only exist at compile time. At runtime, it's just a bunch of bits moving around.

Comment: If you care for C++, (which can be thought of as a superset of C,) and specifically for Microsoft C++, and for the types of objects, not primitive data types, Microsoft does provide RTTI (Run-Time Type Information). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code, you can rely on the fact that the types you are handed correspond to how they were declared. You couldn't write any non-trivial program if that wasn't the case.

Type information, in C, is only available at compile time though. At runtime, none of that information is present so there is no standard build-in way of, for example, telling what type of object is hiding behind a random pointer.
If you need that kind of information, see if your compiler has extensions for it (I don't know if any do), or use frameworks that provide infrastructure for that ([`glib`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) has things like that I believe).
Or roll your own if you *really really* need it.

<sub>Or use C++ which does have some runtime type information support, and generally speaking a more intricate type system, but that's a totally different language.</sub>

Comment: @Mat, Regarding *"You couldn't write any non-trivial program if that wasn't the case."*, so are you saying that there aren't any non-trivial PHP/Javascript programs?

Comment: @Pacerier: PHP and Javascript (and a bunch of others) are dynamically typed and the language semantics are built around that. C is statically typed.

Comment: @Mat, But since it's possible to build non trivial PHP/JS programs without using `typeof` checks, why would that not be possible in C?

Comment: @Pacerier: even if you don't write `typeof` checks explicitly in your code, the runtime/VM for your dynamically typed language does do different things depending on the actual (runtime) type of the expressions involved (e.g. interpreting a string as in integer to do a multiplication). In C, if you end up messing up your (static) types (e.g. bad pointer conversions), you get undefined behavior - there's nothing at runtime that checks the validity of operations.

Comment: @Mat, Actually PHP/JS code don't need to rely on type juggling at all. Not even once. If you don't rely on it then it wouldn't be used. You can imagine that it's like C.

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't understand what you're saying. Javascript does rely on types, a whole lot, at runtime, even if you don't write types explicitly.

Comment: @Mat, I mean you don't need to rely on types at runtime. `typeof` checks are not needed even once throughout a whole non-trivial program.

Comment: @Pacerier: `typeof` checks are irrelevant. When you write `a+b` in Javascript, the meaning of that expression is determined by the runtime type of those two variables, which can be different for every invocation of that expression. This is fundamentally different in C. The types are fixed at compile time, and if you can't rely on the fact that a variable you declared as `int` will in fact be an `int` at runtime (which is what the question is about), you're toast.

Comment: @Mat, You're toast in Javascript too. If you write `a+b` expecting an `int + int` but the inputs happen to be something that is not an `int`, the program may seem to continue running, or it may crash at the next step. Either way, once the `a` and `b` aren't `int`s, you're toasted.

Answer (score 0):

C types primarily exist at compile time.

You can crank up your compilers warning level to get better checking (EG gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall), but I believe some things will still be coerced as needed.

You can use a union for manual type management for some tasks, but in C it's usually better to just rely on your compiler for type checking.